# extracting multiple values from a string VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am dealing with http URLs, all the URLs are correct but some are like:
http://site.com/abgAz1nBs.jpg%20http://site.com/adtEh96Wj.jpg%20http://site.com/acum1N6qN.jpg

so basically these are 3 URLS. I need them to be separated. But it is not the only problem, I need to use "IF" statement to confirm that there is a string that contains multiple "http://" because other URLs are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim strURLToEvaluate As String = "http://site.com/abgAz1nBs.jpg%20http://site.com/adtEh96Wj.jpg%20http://site.com/acum1N6qN.jpg"

Dim strURLs As String() = Strings.Split(strURLToEvaluate, "%20http://")

If strURLs.Length > 1 Then MsgBox("More than one URL!")

For Each strURL In strURLs
    If Strings.Left(strURL, Len("http://")) <> "http://" Then strURL = "http://" & strURL
    MsgBox(strURL)
Next strURL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm:

- Check if the string contains "%20http" (using `String.Contains`).
- If yes, split at "%20http" (using `String.Split`).
- Add "http" at each of the split strings except the first one (using normal string concatenation).

Implementing these steps should be easy and will be (deliberately) left as an exercise to the reader. In fact, after you have implemented them correctly, you might realize that you can skip the first step altogether.